# Create php array with key value pair for an csv file

Tags: php, arrays

I have import a csv file in my controller action. The structure of csv file is like given below.

```
Name , Phone , address
user1 , 99887766 , xyz 
user2, 99885566 , hjj
```

Now I want array of arrays with csv header information as key and row data as value. The required output should be something like this.

```
[
"0" => [ "Name" => "user1" , "Phone" => "99887766" , "address" => "xyz" ],
"1" => [ "Name" => "user2" , "Phone" => "99885566" , "address" => "hjj" ],
]
```

I am able to get the row data with php explode. The problem is in setting the key as header given.
Can anyone help-me for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
 $rows = file($csv_data_file);
 $header = array_shift($rows); //get the header out
 $header = explode(",", $header);
 $final_array = array();
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $row = explode(",", $row);
      $final_array[] = array($header[0] => $row[0], $header[1] => $row[1], $header[2] => $row[2]);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Exploding might be dangerous - if there is a comma in any of the addresses, that row becomes invalid. I suggest using the native function [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876) of creating a general solution for csv to associative arrays. Below is a copy of the function.

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```