# CSV to Key Value Pairs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

Does anyone know if I have a CSV file like:

```
12034564534, Dave
14345643495, Tim
```

And I want to convert them all to a Key Value Pair like:

```
"12034564534" => "Dave",
"14345643495" => "Tim",
```

What would be the best method to achieve this goal?

Comment: Try this [So post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211293/create-php-array-with-key-value-pair-for-an-csv-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$csv = file('myCsv.csv');

foreach($csv as $line) {
    $line = str_getcsv($line);
    $array[$line[0]] = trim($line[1]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [12034564534]=>
  string(5) "Dave"
  [14345643495]=>
  string(4) "Tim"
}
```

Comment: dont use explode on a csv, use the proper csv functions

Comment: @Dagon: Edited accordingly.